# jQuery animate (slide left) on iPad... how can I improve performance?

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad, safari, jquery-animate

I am using:

```
$('selector').animate({marginLeft:'-500px'},600);
```

... to slide a div to the left. Based on my current HTML/CSS, applying a negative margin works and I want to avoid having to rebuild my HTML/CSS to do it another way. My code works great on all browsers, but it's really choppy on a brand new iPad mini. Is there a better way achieve this effect specific to Safari on iOS?

Comment: I do a lot of ipad web development and I've noticed that most jQuery animations don't agree with the device. I've been working with the iPad 3/HD/Whatever, and it doesn't perform much better than the iPad2/Mini for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try out css transitions instead.
http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp

Should be possible with minor changes :)

Comment: I have yet to start using CSS transitions, but maybe this is what's needed. I'll give it a try... I created a jsfiddle that changes the left margin: http://jsfiddle.net/wzSJJ/ and it seems to work nicely. I'll give it a try on the ipad.

Comment: Although I got this jsfiddle example to work, I can't get the exact same transition to work in my real world code. No transition occurs, it just applies the property. Any ideas?

Comment: Ehhh... not really. I have several steps to my transition, the first of which moves the content over to the left and the number of pixels is determined at the time of the transition. I tried creating an inline transition using jquery .css(), but that didn't work either. I think I need to revisit this in depth at a later date. For now, my jquery animations work even though they're not smooth on the ipad.